# Junit testing in a Spring / Maven project

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, junit

I have a problem writing a Junit testcase for a Spring project. Its about the following method;

```
boolean doesUserIdExist(String userId){
        if(userRepository.findOne(userId.toLowerCase()) != null) {
            throw new userAlreadyExistsException("User with id: " + userId + " already exists")
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Now in my jUnit I have something written like this..:

```
void compareDuplicateUserIdTest (){

    UserService UserService = new UserService();

    String lowercase = "test";
    String uppercase = "Test";

    boolean result = userService.doesUserIdExist(lowercase);

    //Check the boolean result if its true

}
```

Since im using the findOne method it means that i'd have to check the String = "test" against the DB userId = "test". This is not the right way since it should work standalone without any records in the MongoDB database.

Now i've been reading about a framework like mockito to test this, but isn't this "too much" for such a simple method check? Can I remove the findOne part and just compare the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a very common problem for unit testing where databases should not be involved (that would be integration testing), so... here is where Mockito is a great tool to use.

Using Mockito allows you to mock your database results and continue with the regular flow of your method, so you could do something like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserService_doesUserIdExistTests
{

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    void compareDuplicateUserIdTest() {

        String lowercase = "test";

        // Mocking the response for your method that uses external dependencies 
        when(userRepository.findOne(lowercase)).thenReturn(true); // You can mock the response you want using .thenReturn(...)

        // Test your userService method (you can also debug it if needed)
        boolean result = userService.doesUserIdExist(lowercase);

        //Check the boolean result if its true
        assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code but shows the idea of testing `userService.doesUserIdExist(...)` method as a unit. Also this is quite helpful when you need to learn by debugging code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll start reading into the mockito framework and implement that into the project. The example you have provided is quite useful :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not too much. The idea of Unit tests is to test method behaviour based on different inputs and insure it behaves as expected. It also documents your expectations and makes refactoring much less painful.

Imagine in the future somebody (may be even you) will decide to remove `userRepository.findOne` from `doesUserExist` method. Your unit test will fail and then the developer will have to figure out if the tests need to be changed due to rafactoring or the refactoring needs to be fixed.

I am not even sure what you'll be testing if you remove `findOne` method and how you are planning to do that.

`Mockito` and `Spring` make mocking really simple. All you need to do is define and initiate mock `userRepository` and then define the behaviour based on the input.

Comment: Great explanation, the theory behind it gives more insight on how to work with jUnit in a Spring project. Thank you :)